# Nodejs not reading the static file

Tags: css, node.js, express

My `Nodejs` application not reading the `express.static` files

code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

but it was not working.

Comment: To answer `express.static()` questions, we have to know 3 things: 1) The full URL being sent to your server, 2) the full path of the file in your file system you wish to have `express.static()` send when that URL is requested and 3) the full path of __dirname (so we can see how the public directory is located relative to __dirname).  The most common problem is that the URL being requested is wrong to match the `express.static()` declaration you have, but without the three items above, we can't offer you anything other than wild guesses.

Comment: Also, when you post here, you should hang around for the next 15-30 minutes so you can answer clarifying questions.  That's the time when the most people see your question and if you aren't hear to clarify, then you'll miss many of the people that could help and your question may also get downvoted or closed for being unclear. Folks here are really helpful with good questions and not so patient when questions are unclear and there is no response to clarifying questions.

Comment: May you also show us the HTML file as well?